# AvPlayer streaming, all the metadata information are in timedMetadata?

Tags: ios, stream, streaming, avplayer

I'm creating an ios app with a streaming player maded with AvPlayer. This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self InitPlayer];

    [self ReadMetaData];
}
-(void)InitPlayer{

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.fakeurl.com/stream"];

    // create a player view controller
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;


}
-(void)ReadMetaData{

    [self.player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"timedMetadata"])
    {
        AVPlayerItem* playerItem = object;

        for (AVMetadataItem* metadata in playerItem.timedMetadata)
        {

            if([metadata.commonKey isEqualToString:@"title"]){

                TitleLabel.text=metadata.stringValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code i can successfully play and pause the stream. I can also print the title of the track. 
If i try to log the timedMetadata with something like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",player.currentItem.timedMetadata);
```

I retrive that:

```
"<AVMetadataItem: 0x15649500, identifier=common/title, keySpace=comn, key class = __NSCFConstantString, key=title, commonKey=title, extendedLanguageTag=(null), dataType=(null), time={21888/44100 = 0.496}, duration={INVALID}, startDate=(null), extras={\n}, value=Keepin-'fake song title>"
```

Now my question is: for that specific stream url the timedMetadata i logged are the only metadata i can retrive? If yes how i can achive a more complex player type (something like "go to next track button","go to previous track button","an history of tracks",ecc...) ? That's the first time i work with stream data and in my expectations there was a lot of information in audio metadata. In real life seems i can get only the track title. There's a problem with my code or the stream source is poor in metadata info?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to find best solution to get metadata from AVPlayer and found it:

```
-(IBAction) BtnGoClick:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://cast.loungefm.com.ua/loungefm"];
    [self setupAVPlayerForURL:url];
}

-(void) setupAVPlayerForURL: (NSURL*) url {
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

    [anItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");
        } else if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Ready to Play");
        } else if (player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");
        }
        }

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"timedMetadata"])
    {
        AVPlayerItem* playerItem = object;

        for (AVMetadataItem* metadata in playerItem.timedMetadata)
        {

            if([metadata.commonKey isEqualToString:@"title"]){

                NSLog(@"%@",metadata.stringValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]